# OpenTTD : How to save complex rail block with signals to use it on other stations

Tags: openttd

I created one complex rails layout design with signals for faster traffic.

I wish to put same layout on another station (use it whenever I have similar stations).

Can I save a particular design block and snap it on an area so I do not have to build it again and again ?

Comment: I'm fairly certain that this isn't possible.

Comment: I asked about this on the OpenTTD forums years ago but the devs rejected it. I'm fairly sure there was a patch you could add to enable this though. It was a bit buggy - I'll try and find it.

Comment: @tombull89 this is answered properly by  TeraTon below. Check it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK in vanilla openTTD this isn't possible, but there is a grf(MOD) that enables this available in openTTD forums [here](http://www.tt-forums.net/viewtopic.php?t=25037)

Comment: Thanks, I got the MOD there. Not tried it out yet. Sorry can not add +1 to your answer due to lack of reputation. Hope they can allow orig questioner to do it for helping.

Comment: You should be able to mark the question as answered, that's different from +1.

Comment: You get points for marking it answered. I also give you points for the question since it's a good one and i'm very interested in the mod as well.

Comment: Ticked answer as solution. As I could not up-vote, I didnt try tick mark also on assumption of similar treatment of it. Thanks.